# openssl Heart bleed Vulnerability

Tags: ssl, openssl, heartbleed-bug

After SSL installation I found that my website is having `Heart bleed Vulnerability`. I am using `openssl 1.0.1.6`. When I am referred some sources it is showing that I need to update my `openssl` version and need to create new private key and then need to do all the procedures for `SSL certificate`. I do not know the SSL certificate vendor will re-issue the `SSL certificate` again. Is there any other solution to solve it? Is there any patches available?Please help guys?

Comment: Heartbleed was relevant in mid 2014. There are tons of information out there on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was using old version of `openssl`. Updated the `openssl`  version to `openssl 1.0.1g` and issue solved!!