# Heart bleed warning issue by Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my application on Google Play (December 2014).After some time i got the warning from Google Play that.

> "We wanted to let you know that your application is statically linking
>   against a version of OpenSSL that has multiple security
>   vulnerabilities for users. Please migrate your app to an updated
>   version of OpenSSL".
>
> "The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with
>   1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via: $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL""
>
> Now someone please explain how i can see the OpenSSL version that my
>   app is using.[here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/resolved-security-problem-with-openssl-app-can-be-removed-on-google-play-whenever/14800/18) i saw that i can check it but it is not showing
>   my app in list using any OpenSSL. I used above method
>
> > $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL""

But not working in my case.

Someone please help how to detect the OpenSSL version of my application.

I know [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492566/openssl-heart-bleed-vulnerability) the same question is exists. But my problem is, How can i see my app's OpenSSL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the OpenSSL file in your APK

Comment: Unzip your APK with an archive manager such s WinRAR (on Windows) or by the command line on Linux.

Comment: yeah , i got it using a String searching software.thank you :)